# ITextRenderer is not accepting the special symbols of html

Tags: java, html, itext

I am using ITextRenderer to generate the pdf using **HTML** String, though its generate the pdf but give me error when the HTML String contain html entity like **&deg**,&nbsp** and so on symbol which output error as

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The entity "deg" was referenced, but not declared.
```

like for example

```
String myString=<html><head></head><body><div>**1L of water at 100&deg;C is mixed with 1 L of water at 0&deg;**</div></body></html>
```

and my java code is

```
 StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
 buf.append(myString);

 try {
          DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

          Document doc = builder.parse(new StringBufferInputStream(buf.toString()));
          ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
          renderer.setDocument(doc, null);
          renderer.getFontResolver();
          renderer.layout();
          java.io.OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
          renderer.createPDF(os);
          os.flush();
          os.close();
      } catch (Exception ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
```

even added meta tag like

```
 <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
```

and also some stuff like

```
<?xml version=\'1.0\' encoding=\'UTF-8\'?><html xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\' lang=\'en\'><head>
```

Still the same error.
Any help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: even i tried using this link " http://www.dayon.nl/content/xhtml-pdf-java-0 " like but show me error " Exception in thread "main" org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). java.io.IOException: Stream closed " where its show that how we can clean the html. but does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is  **&deg;** is considered as a Html tag. So escape the **&** with **&amp;** will solve your problem.

**Example :**

```
 String myString = "<html><head></head><body><div>**1L of water at 100&amp;deg;C is mixed with 1 L of water at 0&amp;deg;**</div></body></html>";
```